# Mount Google Cloud Filestore inside a docker container with Debian

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine, nfsclient, google-cloud-filestore

I want to mount Cloud Filestore inside a docker container which is Debian.

When I try to mount it I get:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Feb 27 12:35:07 2019
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=10.32.222.111,clientaddr=172.17.0.2'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
```

It's running in a Debian VM inside Google Cloud.

Is there any specific port I need to open or firewall to disable ?

What do I have to do in order for the mount to succeed ?

Comment: Are you trying to mount the Filestore instance inside the Docker Container or inside the VM using Docker?

Comment: I am trying locally inside my computer. when I tried with a regular VM (not docker) inside google cloud it works

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Filestore is an NFS to be used [inside](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/#high-performance-file-storage) Google Cloud Compute Engine instances or Kubernetes. It works for any instance in the same VPC. If you wish to use it in your local computer, you will need to connect to this VPC trough a VPN. You could use [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/choosing-a-vpn) to achieve this.