# What docker image does GCP AI notebooks actually use? Cannot mount Cloud Filestore from the deeplearning image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-cloud-filestore

I want to launch an AI Platform Notebook instance with a custom container so I can add some dependencies (e.g., Python 3.7). However, when I run a custom container, I am unable to mount my data from Cloud Filestore.

Per [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/custom-container), I created a custom container using this deep learning image:

> gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-cpu

I didn't make my own container yet and have added zero customizations; I just plugged `gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-cpu` into the console for my custom instance.

When I try to mount my Cloud Filestore, I get the following errors:

```sh
root@c7a60444b0fc:/# mount <IP_ADDRESS>:/streams cfs
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
root@c7a60444b0fc:/# mount -o nolock <IP_ADDRESS>:/streams cfs
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

Now, when I launch a TensorFlow 1.15 notebook from the console (no customizations), the mount works fine and the environment is different from what I get with the deeplearning image. In particular, the deeplearning image launches as the `root` user whereas the TF 1.15 instance launches as the `jupyter` user.

So what image is the GCP AI Notebook actually using? What additional customization does the deeplearning image need to be able to mount a Cloud Filestore?

Comment: As a workaround, I am now using GKE instead of AI Platform Notebooks to host my custom Jupyter container and have made my Cloud Filestore instance a persistent volume that I mount in my Jupyter deployment.

Answer (score 0):

AI Platform Notebooks environments are provided by container images that you select when creating the instance. In this page you will see the available [container image types](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-containers/docs/choosing-container#choose_a_container_image_type).

The problem that you are facing is a [known issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77055/mount-linux-nfs-rpc-statd-is-not-running) and it happens when rpc-statd.service is not initialized. I have solved it following these steps:

- Created a Filestore instance
- Created an AI Platform Notebooks instance with Python
  environment in the same VPC than the Filestore instance
- Entered root mode, installed nfs-common and enabled rpc-statd.service:

  ```
  sudo bash
  sudo apt install nfs-common
  systemctl enable rpcstatd.service
  ```

Using the above commands and following [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/quickstart-gcloud) I could properly mount and access Filestore NFS.

In case that you want to further customize a custom container, you should take into account that in order to get access to Cloud Filestore you will have to use a VPN to connect to the same network as your Filestore instance as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902989/mount-google-cloud-filestore-inside-a-docker-container-with-debian), otherwise you will find a ‘Connection timed out’ error when calling Filestore’s instance internal IP. You could use [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/choosing-a-vpn) to do so.

---